# Django ORM How to use annotated field in filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a queryset:

```
Event.objects.annotate(event_date=Func(F('start_date'), F('end_date'), Value('1 day'), function='generate_series'))
```

Now i want filter all my events where event_date >= value but when i try do

```
queryset.filter(event_date__gte=value)
```

I get error:
argument of WHERE must not return a set
LINE 1: ..., '1 day') AS "event_date" FROM "api_event" WHERE generate_s...

I think its because when i try filter event_date__gte the ORM set again Func and dont use already calculated value event_date

Do you have idea how to use event_date in filter.?

More info here:
[How can get obj between two date range for each date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887471/how-can-get-obj-between-two-date-range-for-each-date)

Comment: you can try convert Func to django query. Or post function generate_series for more clearly

Comment: How can i convert Func to django query?. I need select rows between start_date and end_date with interval 1 day so i need generate_series

Comment: you mean select all `Event` have time `end_date` - `start_date` >= 1 day ?

Comment: You can read this question. Now i have list with date but when i try filter by annotated field i get error( 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887471/how-can-get-obj-between-two-date-range-for-each-date

Comment: You can use annotate fields in a filter query. But the annotated field must have a relevant type. The postgresql function `generate_series` returns a set. What output do you expect here? How would it make sense to compare a single date to a set of dates?

Comment: i want build ORM query like this SQL 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7767452080c8492e16690d8087ce8471

Comment: SO i want make like SELECT * (my_queryset_here) s WHERE s.event_date >= ...